# Store Changes Of Layout Permanently After Closing The Application

Tags: android

**I have a preference layout file, and i want to store all the changes in my layout**

**so the next time I open application it has new changes**

**Example---> Two Radio Buttons in an XML file 1) Blue  (Checked)**
                                             **2) Red   (Unchecked)**

**Now when I Checked it to Red and close The Application then at next time when i run again**

**then it should has this manner in same XML file  1)Blue    (Unchecked)**
                                                 **2)Red     (Checked)**

**so please tell me how I do this.**

**waiting for your reply, thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devang,

You need a [`ChecKBoxPreference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/CheckBoxPreference.html) to store the value in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

This website provides a pretty good tutorial of all of the Preferences types that Android provides and how to save/restore them: http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

Good luck!